# What is the difference between a Cathedral and a Minster?

Tags: differences, religion

In the UK we have a lot of Cathedrals. We also have York Minster but I'm unsure what is special about York that makes it a Minster rather than another Cathedral.

The only other case I can think of is Westminster Abbey although I believe this is named after the City of Westminster.

What does a religious building require to be classed as a Minster rather than a Cathedral?

Comment: Maybe will help: http://www.ask.com/question/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cathedral-and-a-minster

Comment: @nicael I wondered if it was to do with a Bishop - however it's Canterbury Cathedral (where the Archbishop resides).

Comment: "... named after the City of Westminster" it's more like it's the other way round instead.

Comment: We need to show background effort. Include in the question what the dictionary says about each.

Comment: This seems to be a question about Church of England nomenclature, rather than the English language *per se*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about nomenclature of the Church of England

Comment: [There is an SE site dedicated to Christianity.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/) This question would be on-topic there and you would probably get more useful and accurate answers.

Comment: This answer is off-topic because all the OP had to do was visit Wikipedia to find the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OED s.v. *Minster* 2.a.:

> The church of a monastery; a church having its origin in a monastic establishment. More generally: any large or important church, esp. a collegiate or cathedral church. Also more fully *minster church.*

Both *minster* and *abbey* refer to certain large church buildings’ origins as monastic churches. And no, the Borough of Westminster is so named after the monastic foundation that was once there.

When the monasteries of England were dissolved during the reign of Henry VIII, and afterwards, many of their larger churches were retasked as Anglican *cathedrals;* a church is an Anglican *cathedral* if it is the official home church of an Anglican bishop, complete (usually) with the bishop’s throne or *cathedra.* (Other monastic lands and buildings were given by that old pirate Henry VIII to his cronies, with the result that some of the “Stately ’Omes of England” have “Abbey” in their names—including some so called merely pretentiously, a matter of joke near the beginning of Act II of Shaw’s *Mrs Warren’s Profession).*

Whether one of these retasked church edifices continues to be termed “Minster” or is just termed “Cathedral” seems to be up to the vagaries of local custom.

To clarify the answer:

A **Minster** is a Church that has priest(s) that administer to and visit the parishioners. It is open to the public for worship.

A **Cathedral** is a Church in which the throne of an Archbishop is located.

An **Abbey** was originally a Church that was used exclusively by monks. It was not open to the public for worship.

In London Westminster Abbey is complemented by St Paul's Cathedral.
York Minster is both a Cathedral and a Minster.

Comment: Nitpick: although Westminster is a London borough, it's full name is the [City of Westminster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Westminster).

Comment: Yeah, but I got to know it back when the street signs still said "Royal Borough of Westminster."

Answer (score 5):

Minster is an honorific title specific to some churches in England, while Cathedral refers specifically to the 'church' where a Bishop resides.

[Minster:](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minster_%28church%29)

> *Minster is an honorific title given to particular churches in England,* most famously York Minster in York, Westminster in London and Southwell Minster in Southwell. The term minster is first found in royal foundation charters of the 7th century. Although it corresponds to the Latin monasterium or monastery,t then designated any settlement of clergy living a communal life and endowed by charter with the obligation of maintaining the daily office of prayer.

[Cathedral](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral):

> A cathedral (French cathédrale from Latin. cathedra, "seat" from the Greek kathedra (καθέδρα), seat, bench, from kata "down" + hedra seat, base, chair) is a Christian church which contains the seat of a bishop,[1](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minster_%28church%29) thus serving as the central church of a diocese, conference, or episcopate

Answer (score 0):

This isn't simply a question of English Language Usage, but German as well.  The equivalent words in German are Dom and Münster.  The former is the seat of a bishop or archbishop, the latter is not.  In fact, according to the German Wikipedia, "Münster ist ein frühes deutsches Lehnwort aus griech./lat. monasterium, 'Kloster'." or "Münster is an early German loanword out of the Greek/Latin *monasterium*, monastery."

Answer (score -2):

A Minster is a church that is used by missionaries.  It is (usually) the first church built in an area they are attempting to spread the word of God to, or the church that sets up missionary projects in other areas.  You could call it the missionary's 'base of operations' in a way.  York Minster has served in both those roles.

When the (original) Minster in York was built, Christianity hadn't spread through Yorkshire and the people were all Pagans, thus the need for missionaries to spread the faith.

A Minster can be a Cathedral (York being a prime example) however this is not a requirement.  The original York Minster was a small wooden church (not much more than a large hut) which was replaced by other churches and finally the current Minster, all on the same site, and serving the same role.

The York Minster is no longer used for missions in the UK, but does support overseas missions.

Source: Taking the guided tour around the York Minster.

Comment: Sorry to say that the guided tour is promulgating a fable.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minster_(church) for confirmation that @Josh61's answer is correct. The term "minster" has nothing to do with missionary work.